# unable to connect or detect internet single from our router

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu on my wife's HP and for some reason the wireless is not picking up our internet provided by our building.

What can I do? Before we installed Ubuntu we could read our building's internet, now all we are picking up is a personal internet.

Comment: is that wifi networks not detected on your ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Well Ubuntu does not come ready or able to install most wireless NIC cards like you would on any other UNIX or WIN operating system. What HP is it? If you know your model you might be able to find someone that has either found a downloadable pckg driver or a work around. Shoot me an email if I can be of further help.

Comment: it is a hp pavillion that was running windows 7